# Revolution Slider not working properly in firefox

Tags: firefox, revolution-slider

I am developing the website of www.fundacionbiodiversa.org with a revolution slider ver 4.5.6 (the latest available for the theme).
Everything works perfectly in every device EXCEPT for Firefox, where it presents a lot of issues: font colour don't match, slides blink and shake, weird position issues, and others.
Technical support for the theme could not give me an answer. They proposed two "solutions" but none worked:
- http://www.themepunch.com/home/plugins/wordpress-plugins/revolution-slider-wordpress/changes-on-css-documents-has-no-effects-on-frontend/
- http://www.themepunch.com/home/plugins/wordpress-plugins/revolution-slider-wordpress/custom-styles-working/
Any suggestions on what can be the problem?

Comment: I have a positioning issue, with Revo Slider, only in Firefox as well.

Comment: which version of Firefox you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the issues are CSS Related. The style is added inline with the scoped parameter.  This is a failure which we fix in the next minor update 4.6.8 first.

The current available version 4.6.5 and depending on the html header you use, the scoped attribute in firefox is active or not.

To fix all your issues, please update to version 4.6.5 and contact our support at http://themepunch.com/support-center and we will provide you a solution for the css issues also.